# Save file via SSH directly from a url

Tags: ssh

I have two hosting accounts (Host-A and Host-B). Host-A has SSH enabled while Host-B doesn't support SSH. What I want to do is copy a file via SSH from Host-B to Host-A.

Do note I can do this directly as well by first downloading the file from the URL (www.hostb.com/file.zip) and then FTP'ng to the Host-A but this will take fairly a long time because the file is about 2GB.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can ssh to Host-A and `wget www.hostb.com/file.zip`. If you want to browse you can also use a text web browser (w3m, for instance, which is installed by default in some distributions).

Comment: Thanks! You saved me 2gb of bandwidth and lots of time!!